# Navigation position is not correct after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

I have some sticky navigation which gets the custom made class "sticky" when it reaches the top of the page.

This does work fine so far, but when I refresh the page, the position of the navigation gets wrongly detected and is positioned "sticky" immediately after scrolling.

I have these relevant lines of code:

```
var navigation = document.getElementById('navigation'),
    rect = navigation.getBoundingClientRect();
var navigationPosition = rect.top - (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0);

if ( navigationPosition <= 0) {
        if (!navigation.classList.contains('sticky')) {
            navigation.classList.add('sticky');
        }
    } else {
        if (navigation.classList.contains('sticky')) {
            navigation.classList.remove('sticky');
        }
    }
```

I hope you can help me, what am I doing wrong?
Thank you very much!

A way without jquery would be much apreciated, but jQuery should also do the job if needed.

Comment: Try this function 

`function getCoords(elem) { 
  var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

  return {
    top: box.top + pageYOffset,
    left: box.left + pageXOffset
  };

}`

Comment: where exactly shall i put this?

Comment: I added it to the code and said navigationPosition = getCoords(navigation); but this doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this code can help you!

```
    var navigation = document.getElementById('navigation'),
    navigationHeight = navigation.offsetHeight;// or you can set static value



function init() {

    window.addEventListener('scroll', slickNavigation);

    slickNavigation();
}


function slickNavigation() {
    var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;


    if ( scrolled >= navigationHeight) {
            navigation.classList.add('sticky');

    } else {
            navigation.classList.remove('sticky');
    }
}

init();
```

Comment: thanks, this does work fine! I had to add the height of the header to scrolled, so it wont stick too soon, but it does work fine even at the page refresh.